# Can't connect to Oat++ with other WebSocket libraries

Tags: c++, websocket, oat++

Does Oat++ support the RFC 6455 WebSocket protocol?

I tried to connect to an Oat++ WebSocket server from browsers by js, and from `QWebSocket` (qt), but they didn't connect.

Comment: This page says that oat++ does support RFC 6455 and lists several alternatives: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_WebSocket_implementations

Comment: @mmjvox It would be helpful if you would provide details about how you are running/configuring your Oat++ server, and show the client code that is not connecting to it.

Comment: i used  Oat++ websocket server that exists in examples. in client  `ws://localhost:8000` didn't open and disconnected, then i tried to open socket on `http://localhost:8000/ws`.

Comment: It might be enlightening to use Wireshark to record the packets that are sent and received in both the successful-connect and the can't-connect scenarios, and see how they differ between those two cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To connect and test oat++ and other WS servers you may try using this online client:

https://www.websocket.org/echo.html - for WSS
http://www.websocket.org/echo.html - for WS

Also, make sure to connect to a correct endpoint

Comment: I have no logs or errors when I connect to the websocket url. But when I change the url, I have disconnected log. i don't have any firewall and all of other websocket servers and clients are working fine. the oatpp's websocket server only works with oatpp's client. I ran the server from its own examples. I couldn't find any other examples and I didn't read the documents completely yet. Do you have a useful websocket server example in oatpp to test?

Comment: Here is the set of oatpp websocket examples - https://github.com/oatpp/example-websocket

Comment: This example is that one i used and not working with other web socket clients.

Comment: What is your OS, and what exact example-project from the WS examples collection are you trying to run?

Comment: Here is what I do: I take the simple server example - https://github.com/oatpp/example-websocket/tree/master/server, run it. Go to http://www.websocket.org/echo.html , enter the location - ws://localhost:8000/ws, and press "connect".

Comment: Thanks. I'm sorry to create this thread. I changed the server port and i forgot that. on the `const char* pageTemplate` the port is hardcoded, I was wrong because of this.